# Building semantic web using owl security issues

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, owl, protege

I am building owl using user defined semantic relationships. I am using very private information for building the rdf stores. Is it is necessary to specify URI from W3C links? How secured is this? Will this expose my data outside? Can I build owl without specifying external URLs? Please suggest some alternative methods if available.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  The RDF (and OWL) data models use URIs as identifiers.  You don't (have to) *dereference* these URIs;  you never have to attempt to retrieve data from them or send data to them. *"Can I build owl without specifying external URLs[?]"* You can use whatever URIs you want to identify your own resources, but you will need to use the standard OWL, RDF, and RDFS vocabularies in *defining* the ontology.  You can't, e.g., assert that "A is a subclass of B" without writing "A rdfs:subClassOf B", and rdfs:subClassOf is a URI.

Comment: Sorry if I have not mentioned clearly. I am just only concerned with the security issues since I am using very highly confidential data. So I want to confirm the security issues before building the rdf store. I am calling the URIs xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" at various places. Just want to make sure whether the data will be exposed outside or not.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use internal URIs for the RDF, OWL, and other W3 vocabularies.

You can use `owl:sameAs`, `owl:equivalentClass`, `owl:equivalentProperty`, and similar relations between your URIs and the W3-standard URIs, to make plain what you intend by your use of those internal URIs.

This is not recommended, typically for performance reasons, but also because if you get into this habit, you may not use the global standards where you ought when you move to some other position.  There are other reasons.

Given your apparent degree of unfamiliarity with the technologies and how they work, I suggest you build a proof-of-concept with *non-confidential* data, and try to learn how things work -- which should show you that your expressed concerns have no ground to stand on.  If concerns persist, you should at least have better vocabulary and experience to describe your concern -- and we can give you better, more explicit explanations.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understood your question. The answer in short is:

- No, you cannot avoid using the "W3C" URI links. You need to use them to "tag" your data in the right way.
  BUT:
- No worries, this does not compromise the security of your data. When you use these links it is just an internal thing, this will not expose your data outside your domains, your data do not travel to any "W3C" site.